# Running SQL query in VBA with 2 excel files

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to get information from another sheet into my own without copying the needed sheet into my workbook. 
I am managing to make joined queries from the same workbook so i know that adding the needed data into my file will work but i am hoping to avoid this since it is a large file.

Below is my code for adding information from multiple sheets in the same workbook. 
What i need is to get additional information from a second file based on the selected serial number in my own file. 
So i want to know if there is any way of inserting another file name in the From statement (DB Data2.xlsb and DB Other.xlsb

```
Set oCONN = New ADODB.Connection: Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

strSQLSelect = "SELECT distinct `'LV-ALU (2)$'`.MODUS_Nat_ArtNr, `Tabelle1$`.Modul_Typ "
strSQLFrom = " FROM" & _
" `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Excel Sql\DB Data2.xlsb`.`'LV-ALU (2)$'` `'LV-ALU (2)$'`," & _
" `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Excel Sql\DB ***Data2.xlsb***`.`Tabelle1$` `Tabelle1$` "
strSQLWhere = " WHERE `Tabelle1$`.Modus_Nat_ArtNr = `'LV-ALU (2)$'`.MODUS_Nat_ArtNr AND ((`'LV-ALU (2)$'`.Felgendurchmesser='18'))"

strSQL = strSQLSelect & strSQLFrom & strSQLWhere
oCONN.Open strConn
oRS.Open strSQL, oCONN
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `join`?

Comment: You shouldn't really use ADO to query the open workbook, there's a known bug - it causes a memory leak https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/319998

Comment: Hello Shadow, I do not know how to implement your suggestion. I presume i should create 2 different recordsets and join them but i cannot get the syntax right to get a recordset from 2 others. Can you give me an example of an sql on 2 already opened recordsets?

Comment: Hello Kyle, Thank you for the tip. as far as i understood the source of the query should not be open. I just need to extract data not to recalculate or manipulate it further so i will work with the file closed. I hope this will avoid the issue. The example above was just part of the tests i have done. In the proper file i am using a file from the share but it is still being opened in the process for other activities. It is good to know that i should avoid having it open while collecting my data with ADO.